# How to simultaneously test all plugins, theme and db configuration of your wordpress website using phpunit?

Tags: wordpress, phpunit

I've battled with this question for hours now, searching far and wide through the web finding several guides to setup testing for individual plugins which created new a installation of WordPress and created a new empty database as testing ground for said plugin.

However, what I wanted was to test all my plugins at the same time, as many have integrations with each other and have their own configurations already set in the database which would need to be re-inserted into the newly created test database.

So, I simply edited the file bin/install-wp-tests.sh as described below:

In the function `install_wp()` include the line at the end of the function: `cp -a /$USER/wordpress/wp-content/. $WP_CORE_DIR/wp-content/`

In the function `create_db()`, change content of function to:

`mysqldump $USER_wordpress > dump.sql --user="$DB_USER" --password="$DB_PASS"$EXTRA`

`mysqladmin create $DB_NAME --user="$DB_USER" --password="$DB_PASS"$EXTRA`

`mysql $DB_NAME < dump.sql --user="$DB_USER" --password="$DB_PASS"$EXTRA`

(Note: In my case `$USER_wordpress` is the name of the wordpress databse, and `/$USER/wordpress/wp-content/` is the absolute path to wp-content.)

This way, the tests are made using your entire current installation of wordpress including all plugins you've installed or created, and the your current database data.

To load your plugins, you need to specify them on the function `_manually_load_plugin()` on the file tests/bootstrap.php, by including the plugin like so:
`require rtrim( sys_get_temp_dir(), '/\\' ) . '/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/' . 'exampleplugin/exampleplugin.php';`

I've used the following guides:

https://poweredbycoffee.co.uk/unit-testing-with-wordpress/

https://maheshwaghmare.com/wordpress/blog/phpunit-tests/

https://wpmudev.com/blog/unit-testing-wordpress-plugins-phpunit/

https://sanjeebaryal.com.np/fixing-issues-while-setting-up-php-unit-tests-for-wordpress-plugins/

But non of them answered the fundamental question of how to include all your plugins and database configurations for your tests, so you could test multiple plugins inside the same test and using all your plugin configurations already set inside you db.

Comment: Note that some plugins use $wpdb->prefix which is set to 'wptests_' but if you already have those tables using 'wp_' you see to do `global $wpdb; $wpdb->set_prefix('wp_');` before calling require on them in _manually_load_plugin()

Comment: Note that there's functions _delete_all_posts() and _delete_all_data() in /tmp/wordpress-tests-lib/includes/functions.php which delete some tables like wp_users and wp_posts. If you want to keep there takes you'll have to add 'return;' on these functions or just delete where they're called.